Reference to object's primitive attribute
I want to use random.choice(list_champs, weights = list_odds) to select a champion, given their odds. So I need a list of champions and list of their odds.
This is dummy code for what I want to accomplish.
import random

class Champ:
    def __init__(self, odds):
        self.odds = odds
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Champ({self.odds=})"

# create two champs
champ1 = Champ(odds = 0.25)
champ2 = Champ(odds = 0.5)

#create list of champs and their odds
list_champs = [champ1, champ2]
list_odds = [champ.odds for champ in list_champs]

print(f"{list_champs=}")
print(f"{list_odds=}")

# This is what I will be doing with those lists.
random_champ = random.choices(list_champs, weights=list_odds)[0]

# change odds for champ1
print("Changing odds : champ1.odds = 0.99")
champ1.odds = 0.99

# I'd like champ1.odds changes to be reflected in list_odds
print(f"{list_champs=}")
print(f"{list_odds=}")

# So that this will now have different odds.
random_champ = random.choices(list_champs, weights=list_odds)[0]

Output:
list_champs=[Champ(self.odds=0.25), Champ(self.odds=0.5)]
list_odds=[0.25, 0.5]
Changing odds : champ1.odds = 0.99
list_champs=[Champ(self.odds=0.99), Champ(self.odds=0.5)]
list_odds=[0.25, 0.5]

So I have a list of objects, each with attribute 'odds'.
I want to use random.choice(list_champs, weights = list_odds) to select a champ, given their odds.
I will be doing this a lot of times, so performance is a factor here. I do not want to create entire list_odds every time I update some champion's odds.
I could just update both champion.odds in list_champs and their odds in list_odds, but this doesn't seem correct and pythonic.
In short, I'd like to have something like a view (like dict.keys() I guess?) into object's attribute, so that changing its attribute in list_champs will be reflected in list_odds.

The weights can be any sequence, you can create such a "view" by implementing that interface.

"performance is a factor here. I do not want to create entire list_odds every time" - But you're ok with random.choices recomputing the list of cumulative weights every time?

@nocomment thanks for your input. Should I pass cumulative weights into the random.choices? Or how would you do that faster? I tried using random from numpy, but had some problems, I guess that would be much faster, no?

" Internally, the relative weights are converted to cumulative weights before making selections, so supplying the cumulative weights saves work."

Hard to tell. Depends on the details, like how many champs you actually have and how often you change odds. And even if I knew everything, I'd likely have to measure.

I don't know if this is built in anywhere, but you can define a "view" onto a given attribute of objects in a sequence as follows:
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import overload


# use T = TypeVar("T") instead of [T] on Python <3.12, see PEP 695
class AttrView[T](Sequence[T]):

    def __init__(self, seq: Sequence[T], attr: str):
        self._seq = seq
        self._attr = attr

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> T:
        ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> Sequence[T]:
        ...
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return [getattr(value, self._attr) for value in self._seq[index]]
        return getattr(self._seq[index], self._attr)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._seq)

Given your definition of a Champ, you can then use this as follows:
>>> from random import choices
>>> champs = [Champ(0.25), Champ(0.5)]
>>> weights = AttrView(champs, "odds")
>>> for champ in choices(champs, k=10, weights=weights):
...     print(champ)
...
Champ(self.odds=0.25)
Champ(self.odds=0.25)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.25)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)
Champ(self.odds=0.5)


While the AttrView class is ingenuous, it does not tackle the main issue the O.P. has put for: the AttrView sequence is not updated in a transparent way, and have to be re-created before each call to random.choices.  Also, I think it is a bit too much boilerplate, since a generator expression would work just the same ((..., weights=(champ.odd for champ in champs))

@jsbueno in what sense is it not transparent? If you e.g. add items to the seq it references or update the objects referenced within that sequence, those changes will be exposed; you could extract weights in the example I've posted. A generator expression works because of the specific way {cum_,}weights are used; maybe not quite an implementation detail, but it's not strictly a sequence as the docs suggest. (Also I think you mean ingenious, ingenuous is something quite different.)

yes, it was ingenious. What I called  "transparent way" is that the sequence the (AttrView instance) has to be re-generated explicitly  before each call to choices, if champs has been updated.

As for sending a generator instead of a sequence, it works currently, and it would be a weird thing for Python to break such a thing retroactively - although, yes, it is an implementation detail - easily fixable by sending in a list instead of the generator, if it ever breaks - otherwise, it means one fewer pass walking through all items.

@jsbueno "the (AttrView instance)... has to be re-generated explicitly" - no, it doesn't. As I say, you can extract weights, then for example try champs.append(Champ(0.1)) and you'll see len(weights) == 3 and weights[2] == 0.1 accordingly.

If an instance is updated, it will work. But if an instance is erased, or a new one is created, it has to be regenerated. If the instances themselves are static, them this approach works.  - And while thinking about the problem, I wished something like that would exist in the operators package in the stdlib.

@jsbueno it's not at all clear to me what you think the problem is. Instance of what? If a new instance of Champ is created, and added to champs, then weights would reflect that. If an existing Champ's odds were changed, weights would reflect that. It's only if a new instance of list was created that you'd have a problem, e.g. champs = [c for c in champs if c.odds > 0.2].

But yes - the O.P. requirements are just for updating the odds in instances, not updating the champs list itself  - in that case, yes, I'd prefer an approach like this than the generator expression I suggested.

@jsbueno No, AttrView is a proxy for the original sequence. It does not store anything that needs to be regenerated.

Anyway, random.choices will have to iterate over all odds - so, it won't change much the resource usage. But the code may look simpler -
Since each "Champ" instance and its odd have to be in the same order, I think the least complex and more robust thing to do is to embed a choose class method in the Champs class itself.
So:
import random

from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class Champ:
    registry = WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __init__(self, odds):
        self.odds = odds
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Champ({self.odds=})"
    @property
    def odds(self):
        return self.__class__.registry[self] 
    @odds.setter
    def odds(self, value):
        self.__class__.registry[self] =  value
    @classmethod
    def choose(cls):
        return random.choices(list(cls.registry.keys()), weights=cls.registry.values())[0]

There is one thing in there I'd call "advanced feature": the WeakKeyRefDict will perform the magic you asked for: as soon as an instance is deleted, it will vanish from the dictionary altogether, automatically.
If you have more classes where you need this to work, you can put the choose mechanism in a base class, or a mixin.
And I also made odds a property so that if it is updated for an Instance, the value for it in the registry is updated as well.
Here is me using it in the interactive mode (taking some care to use print instead of just displaying the .choose() return value, otherwise ipython will create extra references to the Champ  instances)

In [32]: champs = [Champ(i) for i in (1, 3, 5)]

In [33]: print(*[Champ.choose() for i in range(15)], sep="
    ...: , ")
Champ(self.odds=1), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=1), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=5), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=1), Champ(self.odds=1)

In [34]: del champs[2]

In [35]: print(*[Champ.choose() for i in range(15)], sep="
    ...: , ")
Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=1), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3), Champ(self.odds=3)

In [36]: champs[1].odds=4

In [37]: print(*[Champ.choose() for i in range(15)], sep="
    ...: , ")
Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=4), Champ(self.odds=1)


